# Read more/less without stripping Html tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to implement readmore/less feature. i.e I will be having html content and I am going to show first few characters from that content and there will be a read more link in front of it. I am currently using this code :

```
    var txtToHide= input.substring(length);
    var textToShow= input.substring(0, length);
    var html = textToShow+ '<span class="readmore">&nbsp;&hellip;&nbsp;</span>' 
+ ('<span class="readmore">' + txtToHide+ '</span>');
    html = html + '<a id="read-more" title="More" href="#">More</a>';
```

Above input is the input string and length is the length of string to be displayed initially.
There is an issue with this code, suppose if I want to strip 20 characters from this string:
`"Hello <a href='#'>test</a> output"`, the html tags are coming between and it will mess up the page if strip it partially. What I want here is that if html tags are falling between the range it should cover the full tag i.e I need the output here to be `"Hello <a href='#'>test</a>"` . How can I do this

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Hi Marcel, I need the output to be "Hello <a href='#'>test</a>" not "Hello test". I don't want to strip html tags.

Comment: Yes, but then you still need to know which closing tag accompanies the starting tag, which might become problematic when nested elements come in sight, e.g. `<a id="first"><a id="second">test</a></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just hide the hidden part of the content instead of adding it later? I usually just use a `display: none` for hidden content and have it set to `display: block` when the read more is clicked..

Comment: This. The OPs problems are stemming from a lack of SoC - let the markup be the markup and handle the behaviour appropriately with CSS/JS. FWIW I would be toggling a `removed` class rather than applying style directly.

Comment: I need to include the anchor tag in the visible text.

Comment: @annakata, of course the `display: none` would have to go into a class, you're right. And Rocky, that's not a problem. I think you're staring yourself blind on a problem that's not so hard to solve actually.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I'm sorry I didn't read the question good enough.
This should work though:

```
<div id="test">
This <a href="http://www.google.com">links to google</a> 
<strong>and</strong> some random text to make it a little bit longer!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   var max_length = 21;
   var text_to_display = "";
   var index = 0;
   var full_contents = $("#test").contents();

   // loop through contents, stop after maxlength is reached
   $("#test").contents().each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).text().length + text_to_display.length < max_length) {
            text_to_display += $(this).text();
            index++;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

   // second loop removes unwanted content
   $("#test").contents().each(function(i) {
        if (i > index) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
        return true;
   });

   // add link to show the full text
   $('<a href="#">read more...</a>').click(
    function(){
        $("#test").html($(full_contents));
        $(this).hide(); 
    }).insertAfter($("#test"));
 });
</script>
```

This can be accomplished quite easilly using jQuery

```
<div id="test">This <a href="http://www.google.com">is a link to google</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("#test").text());
 });
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't want to strip it. I just want to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the html tags would become an issue, so why not remove in the string conversion and replace with plain text, then on the Show More click, Toggle plain + Html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Contents = $('#post p'); //Object

    var Plain = Contents.text(); //truncate this

    //Hide the texts to Contents
    Contents.hide();

    var PlainContainer = $("<div>").addClass("Plain_Container").val(Plain)

    //Add PlainContainer div after
    Contents.append(PlainContainer);


    var $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(Plain_Container).remove(); //Delete it

        Contents.Show(); //Show the orginal

        $(this).remove(); //Remove the link

        return false; //e.PreventDefault() :)
    });
});
```

This way using the `text()` function will convert html tags to there values and remove the tag itself, all you have to do is toggle them :)

Note: *The code above is not guaranteed to work and is provided as example only.*

Comment: I need to include the anchor tag in the visible text. I don't want it to display as plain text.